# MySQL Connection Failed - more than "max_user_connections" active connections

Tags: mysql, database

I get this error not when running website code, but from running a ton of queries in my Mac database app called Querious.  I just checked and max_user_connections is set to 50.  Will increasing this to 100 help?

Comment: It should, until you reach 100 connections. Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: These both are big numbers, and Querious looks like a single user app. I doubt you are executing 50+ concurrent queries using just it. If it occurs with only Querious running, there's something wrong with Querious. If your website is running at 49 connections, and this is pushing it over, its a website problem. Enable your slow query log.